# $\lim_{x\to p} f(x)=0 \iff \lim_{x\to p}| f(x)|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

$(\implies)$

Suppouse that $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=0$. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $0<|x-p|<\delta \implies |f(x)-0|<\epsilon$.

$||f(x)| - |0|| \leq |f(x)-0|<\epsilon$, so $||f(x)| - |0|| <\epsilon$, and since $|0|=0$ we have that $||f(x)| - 0| <\epsilon$.

$(\Longleftarrow)$

So, no we must suppouse that $\lim_{x\to p}|f(x)|=0$. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $0<|x-p|<\delta \implies ||f(x)|-0|<\epsilon$. So the first direct is the case.

Can anyone help me to prove this second part? I can't see how

Comment: $||f(x)|-0|$ is same as $|f(x)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $\lim_{x\to p} f(x)=0$. Note that $|f(x)|=||f(x)||$.

Every definition is "if and only if" so the following holds:

$$\lim_{x\to p} f(x)=0 \iff (\forall\epsilon\gt0)(\exists\delta\gt0)( \forall x\in (p-\delta,p+\delta)\setminus\{p\}\implies |f(x)|\lt\epsilon)\iff (\forall\epsilon\gt0)(\exists\delta\gt0)( \forall x\in (p-\delta,p+\delta)\setminus\{p\}\implies ||f(x)||\lt\epsilon)$$

Noting that $||f(x)||=||f(x)|-0|$, it follows that $\lim_{x\to p}|f(x)|=0$.

Your proof is also correct for the first part. To complete the proof in OP, just note that $|f(x)|=||f(x)||=||f(x)|-0|$ and then you are done.